# IBM CMOD Java API fails under stress conditions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, content-management-system, ecm

We've implemented a Java software that uses IBM Content Manager OnDemand as it's ECM repository. We've used many versions of this product, from version 8.3.0.0 up to 8.5.0.8 with it's CMOD Web Enablement Kit (ODWEB) Java API and, in several platforms such as AIX, Windows and Linux, using Weblogic, JBoss and IBM WAS as App Servers.

No matter which CMOD, OS or AS version we use we also get the same problem: under heavy load the API (native libraries) seem to fail, answering with spontaneous messages like "Users has no access", when the user has not changed at all, "Cannot open folder", and things like that.

Everything suggests either:

- We have quite a bug when dealing with CMOD API
- CMOD still has some kind of issue that collapses under heavy load conditions.

Has anyone come across something similar? Any hints? What else should I provide as a basis for analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have a bug or something like that, or maybe even a server side issue. I have never seen our systems come down under heavy loading, I have seen stress on the boxes while running AFP2PDF and such but never so much as to make the server crash.

The only thing I can suggest, is increasing the heapsize on your box that runs ODWEK, and make sure that you are up to date. We ran 8.5.0.6 BACKEND with 8.4.0.3 FRONT END while troubleshooting an isssue. I would open a PMR with IBM

Comment: I too never had any such issues using ODWEK 9.0